ALSA dmix plugin unusual sample rate
In my embedded project, I am trying to use ALSA dmix plugin. But, when I use dmix plugin with plug plugin, there is a problem such as bold sound that it should not be.
My asound.conf file, in /etc dir, organized such as this:
Organization-1 : route plugin -> plug plugin -> hw slave plugin
Organization-2 : route plugin -> plug plugin -> dmix plugin -> hw slave plugin

When organization-1 is used, there is no problem. But, when organization-2 is used there is a bold sound problem.
Note that I am playing music (a wav file) with aplay or gstreamer.
